# View ICMP settings with Command Window (CMD)

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, remote-desktop, ping

**Short question**: Is there a simple 1-line command in CMD, executed locally by a user on the host, which tells whether ICMP is allowed or blocked?

**Background**: Some computers in the network are reachable by RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) but not by a `ping`-request (response is `Request timed out`). This is most likely due to ICMP being blocked. I'd like to make the current user of the host to view the ICMP settings locally on that specific host. However, I only find instructions how to allow / block ICMP or how to view the settings in `Control Panel > ...`. Best would be, if a user of the host could view (not only test) locally the ICMP settings with a 1-line command in CMD (Command Prompt).

Comment: Several factors can prohibit ICMP from working (eg, Windows Firewall, anti-virus access protection rules, IPv4 vs IPv6 configs, sandboxing/virtualized containers, etc); some of which are not isolated to the local target system (eg, external firewalls/proxy servers, bad subnet mask configs, bad routes, NAT/VIP configs, etc.).  Therefore, I am fairly certain there's no simple 1-line command that can ultimately determine whether or not ICMP is allowed to your target system from multiple network sources.

Comment: expanding on leeharvey's comment: if you can list the block sources applying in regard to your system, it would be possible to put them all into one function, essentially achieving your goal of a single line command